# can I use both php and java for a same web application

Tags: java, php

I want to use php in place of jsp/servlets for my web app whose service layer and database layer has been written in java. It is possible to do so? If yes, can a web hosting server run both of them simultaneously?

Comment: have a look http://php-java-bridge.sourceforge.net/

Comment: This link might be helpful. http://php.net/manual/en/book.java.php

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Palava](https://github.com/palava/palava-docs). Our main goal of this framework is exactly want you want:

- PHP Scripts instead of JSP/Servlets, but
- a reliable and fast Java backend

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is probably to have one php webserver and one servlet container such as tomcat. You can configure tomcat to run on a different port such as 8080 and use apaches [mod_proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_proxy.html) to make the servlet container available on port 80.

Here's what my configuration looks like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin emil@mydomain.com
        ServerName mydomain.com

        ProxyRequests Off

        <Proxy *>
                Order deny,allow
                Allow from all
        </Proxy>

        ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/

</VirtualHost>
```

There's also a PHP implementation in Java called [Quercus](http://www.caucho.com/resin-3.0/quercus/). I haven't tried it, but it might be worth checking out.

The last time it tried the php-java-bridge, it seemed rather slow. However, that was back in 2007, so things might have changed.

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at http://php-java-bridge.sourceforge.net/pjb/FAQ.html
Or, as mentioned before use mod_proxy.
Yet another way would be to setup java locally and have php call some sort of REST or SOAP java api to get the data and then display it.